# How to get python wildcard and re in a for loop

Tags: python, indexing, python-re

Trying to run re expression through a loop and map a variable to its output.

```
import re
var_name = ['h5_vort', 'h5_temp','sfc']
for var in var_name:
    if var == [string for string in var_name if re.match(re.compile('h5.'),string)]:
        lev=500.0
    else:
        lev=200.0
    print(var)
    print(lev)
```

The output I am getting is

```
h5_vort
200.0
h5_temp
200.0
sfc
200.0
```

I am expecting

```
h5_vort
500.0
h5_temp
500.0
sfc
200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regular expression.

Simply check if **h5** is in the current string.

```py
var_name = ['h5_vort', 'h5_temp','sfc']
for var in var_name:
    if 'h5' in var:
        lev=500.0
    else:
        lev=200.0
    print(var)
    print(lev)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to coding and tend to over complicate things

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using re.compile inside of a loop.  The `re` module will automatically take care of that.

Second, you've got a loop inside of a loop.  The expression

```
[string for string in var_name if re.match(re.compile('h5.'),string)]
```

is going to give you `[h5_vort, h5=temp]`, and neither of your variables is going to be `==` to that, so it's going to be False every time.

You should want `if re.match('h5.', var):` or something like that.